# Create multiple sets of plus and minus buttons with TextView on same page of App (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, input, output

I have two controls that i can increase or decrease an integer. I click on either the first or second set of plus and minus buttons,despite being separate functions, it'll display the Integers on both outputs. For example if I click on the plus and minus button for the integer_number_1, it'll display the numbers on both the integer_number_1 and integer_number_2 outputs/TextView.

How do I fix this??? I've so many different ways and none of them worked.

[image: screenshot]

Here's my xml section:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="549dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decrease_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/integer_number_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="70sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/increase_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/decrease_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/integer_number_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.513"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.317" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/increase_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.579"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/integer_number_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.313" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/integer_number_2"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.426"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.297" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here's my kt file:

```
package com.example.plus_and_minus_input

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    increase_1.setOnClickListener { increaseInteger1() }
    decrease_1.setOnClickListener { decreaseInteger1() }


    increase_2.setOnClickListener { increaseInteger2() }
    decrease_2.setOnClickListener { decreaseInteger2() }


}

fun increaseInteger1() {
    display(integer_number_1.text.toString().toInt() + 1)
}

fun decreaseInteger1() {
    display(integer_number_1.text.toString().toInt() - 1)
}


fun increaseInteger2() {
    display(integer_number_2.text.toString().toInt() + 1)
}

fun decreaseInteger2() {
    display(integer_number_2.text.toString().toInt() - 1)
}

private fun display(number: Int) {
    integer_number_1.setText("$number")
    integer_number_2.setText("$number")
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to separate this following display methods.

```
private fun display(number: Int) {
    integer_number_1.setText("$number")
    integer_number_2.setText("$number")
}
```

to

```
private fun display_number_1(number: Int) {
    integer_number_1.setText("$number")
}
```

and

```
private fun display_number_2(number: Int) {
    integer_number_2.setText("$number")
}
```

Comment: Also I'm trying to set my decrement limit to 0 and increment limit to 10. I tried using               if(integer_number_1.text.length < 0) {
                integer_number_1.text.length === 0
            }                                                                                                                      
 Then I tried using setText("0") and none of them worked. What do you recommend?

Comment: I think 'integer_number_1.text.length' is String size.
0-9 -> size is 1.
-1 or 10 -> size is 2.
abc -> size is 3.

You'd better change the type String to Int.

fun increaseInteger1() {
  val stringNumber = integer_number_1.text.toString() // "1"
  val intNumber = stringNumber.toInt() // 1
  val increasedNumber = intNumber + 1 // 2
  if(increasedNumber < 0) { display_number_1(0) } 
  else if (increasedNumber > 10) {display_number_1(10)}
}